# NextJS query only accessible via param String, not via Router.push - option

Tags: react-router, next.js, next-router

The issue I am having is regarding passing parameters from one page to another.
I have two components: Registration and Success.
Inside my Registration Component, if the user successfully registers, he will be redirect to the Success Component. Depending on whether he is underaged, additional info will be rendered on the Success Component.

Relevant part inside my Registration Component:

```
if (!errors) {
      Router.push(`${REDIRECT_ON_SUCCESS}?showParentalConsent=${showParentalConsent}`, REDIRECT_ON_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Relevant part inside the Success Component:

```
  const {
    query: { showParentalConsent },
  } = useRouter();
```

and

```
{showParentalConsent === 'true' && 
          SomeText}
```

This does work, but passing the Parameter as an option does not.

What I tried:

Inside Registration Component I changed the `push` command to:

```
Router.push({ pathname: REDIRECT_ON_SUCCESS, query: { showParentalConsent: showParentalConsent } , REDIRECT_ON_SUCCESS)
```

But the value of `showParentalConsent` in that case will always be `undefined`.
What am I missing?

Oh and right now I am not using Redux, which would make that a lot easier.